# Upload JS file on asset library

Tags: javascript, file-upload

We have a SharePoint 2013 enviroment were we are unable to upload JS file to a an asset library from client machine, while it work ok if we upload from inside the server.

How can we resolve the issue?

Error From SP Designer

> Could not find a web server at www.thedomain.com on port 80. Please check to make sure that the web server name is
>   Valid and your proxy settings are set correctly. If you are sure that everything is correct, the web server may be
>   Temporarily out of service.

Error from web Browser

> Something went wrong

This error is random and it worked also in some rare case. This issue is specially with JS file and HTML with JS. It works ok with text file.

Comment: Has the user permissons to upload?

Comment: Yes, user is site collection admin and as mentioned he is able to do the same from inside the server but facing issue while doing same from client machine.

Comment: Are you tried in IE?

Comment: What error you are getting

Comment: yes, we also tried in IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long investigation we found that antivirus of the enterprise PC was creating the issue.We added exception for sharepoint designer exe on the antivirus client which resolves the issue.